# Information on thermal zones

Tags: android, adb, hardware

Where to find information on thermal zone?

When I put the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

I will then get the following down below as a result.

```
xo-therm-adc
xo-therm-605-step
wlan-usr
vbat_too_low
vbat_low
```

But I am wondering where can I get more information on what `xo-therm-adc` is exactly?

Comment: What is the output of `find /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0 -type f -exec grep 'xo-therm-adc' {} \; 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Darkman I would get `xo-therm-adc` as an output

Comment: Huh sorry, forgot to add a `-l` (lowercase L) flag to `grep`. If this `find /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0 -type f -exec grep -l 'xo-therm-adc' '{}' \; 2>/dev/null` gives you `sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`, then I've no other ideas of how to help you.